# Xor Cipher Explanation

Tags: bash, encryption, posix, xor

I was trying to make a XOR cipher that takes two decimal values and xor them together when I came across the code below, I need to help in understanding what this is actually doing and how can I use this to make my own cipher

So far I have taken input for key and string and then I am trying to convert that string to binary using `xxd -bi`, But the answer seems weird, so I shifted to `bc`, once I get the answer can I simply do `binary(String) ^ key`

If not what's the correct way?

```
xor() {                                                                                                 
    key=$1                                                                                               │
    length=${#key}                                                                                       │
    while read -r -N1 byte                                                                               │
    do                                                                                                   │
        char=${key:$((i % length)):1}                                                                    │
        ((i++))                                                                                          │
        echo $((byte ^ char))                                                                            │
    done                                                                                                 │
}
```

Comment: You can take your approach to `xor`, but you need to output in a fixed width for each char so you can read them back. Would suggest adding `printf -v byteval "%d" "'$byte"; printf -v charval "%d" "'$char"` under `{(i++))` and output as `printf "%02x" $((byteval ^ charval))` to format each of the `xor`ed values as a 2-digix hex value. You can then decode with `while read -r -N2 byte`, but the difficulty is converting the numeric value held in a variable back to a literal character. (a lookup table seems the easiest choice). Others may have a magic way for reverse conversion.

Answer (score 0):

There are probably more concise ways to handling the character conversions, but in your `xor` function, you need to encode each `xor'ed` character as a 2-digit hex value. That way you can read in the encoded string and decode each 2-digit hex value. For example:

```
## endcode string on stdin to 2-digit hex using key
xor() {
    local key="$1"
    local length=${#key}
    while read -r -N1 byte
    do
        char=${key:$((i % length)):1}
        ((i++))
        printf -v byteval "%d" "'$byte"
        printf -v charval "%d" "'$char"
        printf "%02x" $((byteval ^ charval))
    done
    echo""
}
```

(**note:** the single-quote prefix before `"'$byte"` and `"'$char"` to force the literal character value conversion)

The decoding is a bit more involved. To perform the reverse `xor` to get the original string back, you must prepare a variable holding a formatted hex or octal literal representation of the result of the `xor` (e.g. `\0num` for octal or `\xnum` for hex). You may then use this *Unquoted* variable as the `printf` format string to get the original character. Example decode:

```
## decode 2-digit hex string to text using key
decode() {
    local key="$1"
    local length=${#key}
    local res=
    local out=
    while read -r -N2 byte
    do
        char=${key:$((i % length)):1}
        ((i++))
        printf -v byteval "%d" "0x$byte"
        printf -v charval "%d" "'$char"
        res=$((byteval ^ charval))
        printf -v out "\\\x%02x" $((byteval ^ charval))
        if [ "$res" -gt '0' ]; then
            printf $out
        else
            printf " "
        fi
    done
    echo""
}
```

(note: I needed to check for a zero value as the space was decoded as `0` instead of `20`. The reason is `' '` (space) in binary is `00100000`. Note the 6th bit is the only `1` in the string. The 6th bit also just happens to correspond to the *lower-case* bit -- meaning for any `A-Z` if you set the 6th bit you get `a-z`. Thus if you `xor` a `space` with any lowercase character (your `"xyz"` key for instance), you lose the ability to get the space back)

Using bash a *herestring* can be used to feed the string values to each `xor` and `decode`. Putting the pieces together, you could do:

```
#!/bin/bash

## endcode string on stdin to 2-digit hex using key
xor() {
    local key="$1"
    local length=${#key}
    while read -r -N1 byte
    do
        char=${key:$((i % length)):1}
        ((i++))
        printf -v byteval "%d" "'$byte"
        printf -v charval "%d" "'$char"
        printf "%02x" $((byteval ^ charval))
    done
    echo""
}

## decode 2-digit hex string to text using key
decode() {
    local key="$1"
    local length=${#key}
    local res=
    local out=
    while read -r -N2 byte
    do
        char=${key:$((i % length)):1}
        ((i++))
        printf -v byteval "%d" "0x$byte"
        printf -v charval "%d" "'$char"
        res=$((byteval ^ charval))
        printf -v out "\\\x%02x" $((byteval ^ charval))
        if [ "$res" -gt '0' ]; then
            printf $out
        else
            printf " "
        fi
    done
    echo""
}

[ -z "$1" ] && {    ## validate key given
    printf "error: insufficient input - key\n"
    exit 1
}
key="$1"

read -r line        ## read input string on stdin
[ -z "$line" ] && { ## validate input string provided
    printf "error: no string input on stdin.\n"
    exit 1
}

printf "original: %s\n" "$line"         ## output original string

encoded=$(xor "$key" <<<$line)          ## encode and output encoded string
printf "encoded : %s\n" "$encoded"

decoded=$(decode "$key" <<<"$encoded")  ## decode and output decoded string
printf "decoded : %s\n" "$decoded"
```

(**note:** I'm sure there are more elegant ways to handle this)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ echo "I am the string" | bash bashxor.sh xyz
original: I am the string
encoded : 31791b15790e101c7a0b0d0811171d78
decoded : I am the string
```

Look thing over and let me know if you have further questions. Bash alone is not an ideal platform to perform low-level encoding/decoding with. If this is not a learning exercise, then look at using the tools provided by openssl to accomplish the same things -- properly.